# How to get animation info in After Effects for developers? not Lottie

Tags: flutter-animation, after-effects

I am developing an app using `flutter`. My UI design uses **After Effects** to do a nice set of interactive animations that include elements in the page, obviously I can't do it with **Lottie**. But currently searching for **After Effects** export animation information only gives me **Lottie** related information.I already know how to implement animation with `flutter`, but I don't know detailed animation information.

Is there any other way to get animation information from **After Effects**, including duration, animation curve, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an [AE plugin](https://google.github.io/inspectorspacetime/) that can export animation parameters。